# Как добавить свои элементы в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть такие таблички:

Сначала изображений таблиц
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это код первой таблицы

```
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #2e2a2a;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif, Verdana;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    color: #e95846;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.pricing-table-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2.6em;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.pricing-table-title a {
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    clear: both;
}
/** ========================
 * Contenedor
 ============================*/
.pricing-wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 40px auto 0;
}

.pricing-table {
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.pricing-table:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.06);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.06);
    -o-transform: scale(1.06);
    transform: scale(1.06);
}

.pricing-title {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #e95846;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.pricing-table.recommended .pricing-title {
    background: #2db3cb;
}

.pricing-table.recommended .pricing-action {
    background: #2db3cb;
}

.pricing-table .price {
    background: #403e3d;
    font-size: 3.4em;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.pricing-table .price sup {
    font-size: 0.4em;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
}

.table-list {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #403d3a;
}

.table-list li {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 12px 8px;
}

.table-list li:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #3fab91;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
} 

.table-list li span {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.table-list li span.unlimited {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #e95846;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 38px;
    -moz-border-radius: 38px;
    border-radius: 38px;
}


.table-list li:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #F0F0F0;
}

.table-buy {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.table-buy p {
    float: left;
    color: #37353a;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2.4em;
}

.table-buy p sup {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
}

.table-buy .pricing-action {
    float: right;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #e95846;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.table-buy .pricing-action:hover {
    background: #cf4f3e;
}

.recommended .table-buy .pricing-action:hover {
    background: #228799;    
}

/** ================
 * Responsive
 ===================*/
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    .pricing-wrapper {
        width: 768px;
    }

    .pricing-table {
        width: 236px;
    }
    
    .table-list li {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }

 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .pricing-wrapper {
        width: 420px;
    }

    .pricing-table {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .pricing-wrapper {
        width: 300px;
    }
} 
</style>








<!-- Contenedor -->
    <div class="pricing-wrapper clearfix">
        <!-- Titulo -->
        

        <div class="pricing-table">
            <h3 class="pricing-title"> Інформаційний Каталог</h3>
            <div class="price">Вільний доступ</div>
            <!-- Lista de Caracteristicas / Propiedades -->
            <ul class="table-list">
                <li>Позначення Нормативного документу</li>
                <li>Назва Нормативного документу </li>
                <li>Кількість сторінок Нормативного документу </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Contratar / Comprar -->
            <div class="table-buy">

                <a href="#" class="pricing-action">Отримати доступ</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        


        <div class="pricing-table">
            <h3 class="pricing-title"> Каталог +</h3>
            <div class="price">200<sup>грн/ місяць</sup></div>
            <!-- Lista de Caracteristicas / Propiedades -->
            <ul class="table-list">
                <li>Код згідно з НК 004 </li>
                <li>Позначення Нормативного документу</li>
                <li>Назва Нормативного документу</li>
                <li>Чиність Нормативного документу в Україні</li>
                <li>Кількість сторінок Нормативного документу</li>
                <li>Наявність змін та поправок до НД</li>
                <li>Позначення НД який замінено</li>
                <li>Наказ про прийняття НД</li>
                <li>Скасовується</li>
                <li>Мова</li>
                <li>Метод прийняття</li>
                <li>Технічний комітет</li>
                <li>Познака директиви</li>
                
            </ul>
            <!-- Contratar / Comprar -->
            <div class="table-buy">
                <p>200<sup>грн/ місяць</sup></p>
                <a href="#win1" class="pricing-action">Отримати доступ</a>

            

            </div>
                
        </div>
    </div>
   <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="win1"></a>
   <div class="popup">

   <style>
   .simple-little-table {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    font-size:12px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
    background:#eaebec;
    margin:20px;
    border:#ccc 1px solid;
    border-collapse:separate;
 
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
}
 
.simple-little-table th {
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:21px 25px 22px 25px;
    border-top:1px solid #fafafa;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
 
    background: #ededed;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#ebebeb));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed,  #ebebeb);
}
.simple-little-table th:first-child{
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.simple-little-table tr:first-child th:first-child{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:3px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
}
.simple-little-table tr:first-child th:last-child{
    -moz-border-radius-topright:3px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:3px;
    border-top-right-radius:3px;
}
.simple-little-table tr{
    text-align: center;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.simple-little-table tr td:first-child{
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:20px;
    border-left: 0;
}
.simple-little-table tr td {
    padding:18px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 
    background: #fafafa;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fbfbfb,  #fafafa);
}
.simple-little-table tr:nth-child(even) td{
    background: #f6f6f6;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8f8f8), to(#f6f6f6));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f8f8f8,  #f6f6f6);
}
.simple-little-table tr:last-child td{
    border-bottom:0;
}
.simple-little-table tr:last-child td:first-child{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}
.simple-little-table tr:last-child td:last-child{
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}
.simple-little-table tr:hover td{
    background: #f2f2f2;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2f2f2), to(#f0f0f0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f2f2f2,  #f0f0f0);
}
 
.simple-little-table a:link {
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.simple-little-table a:visited {
    color: #999999;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.simple-little-table a:active,
.simple-little-table a:hover {
    color: #bd5a35;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
</style>


    <input img="
    <a class="close"title="Закрыть" href="#close"></a>
    </div>
<style>
/* Стили кнопки */
.iksweb{display: inline-block;cursor: pointer; font-size:19px;text-decoration:none;padding:10px 34px; color:#0d0d0d;background:#26d162;border-radius:56px;border:2px solid #36c769;}
.iksweb:hover{background:#354251;color:#ffffff;border:2px solid #354251;transition: all 0.2s ease;}
</style>

        <style>

        /* Базовые стили слоя затемнения и модального окна  */
.overlay {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
/* фон затемнения */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    position: fixed; /* фиксированное поцизионирование */
    cursor: default; /* тип курсара */
}
/* активируем слой затемнения */
.overlay:target {
    display: block;
}
/* стили модального окна */
.popup {
    top: -100%;
    right: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 20;
    margin: 10;
    width: 85%;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 800px;
/* фиксированное позиционирование, окно стабильно при прокрутке */
    position: fixed;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #383838;
    background: #fefefe;
/* скругление углов */
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font: 14px/18px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
/* внешняя тень */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.22),0 19px 60px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -500%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
}
/* активируем модальный блок */
.overlay:target+.popup {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: 20%;
}
/* формируем кнопку закрытия */
.close {
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 13px/20px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .8s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .8s;
    -ms-transition: all ease .8s;
    -o-transition: all ease .8s;
    transition: all ease .8s;
}
.close:before {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    content: "X";
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    font-size: 12px;
}
.close:hover {
    background-color: rgba(252, 20, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);    
}
/* изображения внутри окна */
.popup img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
/* миниатюры слева/справа */
.pic-left, 
.pic-right {
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
}
.pic-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 15px 5px 0;
}
.pic-right {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 15px;
}
/* элементы м-медиа, фреймы */
.popup embed, 
.popup iframe {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}
.popup h2 { /* заголовок 2 */
    margin: 0;
    color: #008000;
    padding: 5px 0px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #adadad;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
/* параграфы */
.popup p {margin: 0; padding: 5px 0}
</style>
```

Это код второй таблицы

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Інформаційний Каталог</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tablewrapper">
        <div id="tableheader">
            <div class="search">
                <select id="columns" onchange="sorter.search('query')"></select>
                <input type="text" id="query" onkeyup="sorter.search('query')" />
            </div>
            <span class="details">
                <div>Records <span id="startrecord"></span>-<span id="endrecord"></span> of <span id="totalrecords"></span></div>
                <div><a href="javascript:sorter.reset()">reset</a></div>
            </span>
        </div>






        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table" class="tinytable">

            <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th><h3>позначення НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>назва НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3>чинність НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3> кількість сторінок в НД</h3></th>
                        <th><h3> Придбати</h3></th>
                    </tr>


            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","work2");
                    $db->set_charset("utf8");
                    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM katalog");
                    $_r = $sql->num_rows;
                    if ($_r > 0)
                    {
                        while ($tablerows = $sql->fetch_array())
                        {
                            echo '
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[1].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[5].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[7].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a>'.$tablerows[16].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a> '.$tablerows[23].'</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            
                            
                            ';
                            
                            
                        }                       
                        
                    }else{
                        echo '<tr><td colspan=4 style="text-align: center;">Ничего нет</td></tr>';
                    }

                ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="tablefooter">
          <div id="tablenav">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/first.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1,true)" />
                    <img src="images/previous.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1)" />
                    <img src="images/next.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(1)" />
                    <img src="images/last.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Last Page" onclick="sorter.move(1,true)" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select id="pagedropdown"></select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="javascript:sorter.showall()">view all</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tablelocation">
                <div>
                    <select onchange="sorter.size(this.value)">
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                    <span>Entries Per Page</span>
                </div>
                <div class="page">Page <span id="currentpage"></span> of <span id="totalpages"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var sorter = new TINY.table.sorter('sorter','table',{
        headclass:'head',
        ascclass:'asc',
        descclass:'desc',
        evenclass:'evenrow',
        oddclass:'oddrow',
        evenselclass:'evenselected',
        oddselclass:'oddselected',
        paginate:true,
        size:10,
        colddid:'columns',
        currentid:'currentpage',
        totalid:'totalpages',
        startingrecid:'startrecord',
        endingrecid:'endrecord',
        totalrecid:'totalrecords',
        hoverid:'selectedrow',
        pageddid:'pagedropdown',
        navid:'tablenav',
        sortcolumn:1,
        sortdir:1,
        sum:[8],
        avg:[6,7,8,9],
        columns:[{index:7, format:'%', decimals:1},{index:8, format:'$', decimals:0}],
        init:true
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не нужно весь ваш код тащить в вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @KAGGDesign, просто насколько я прочитал про wordpress , может потребоваться создать свой шаблон который должен соответствовать стандарту wordpress

Comment: Вы хоте в админке создать страницу или куда перетащить?

Comment: Для всего этого есть готовые плагины. Выбирай какой понравится: по первой картинке https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/price+table по второй https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/table

Comment: @Denisoed создать страницу на сайте

Comment: @SeVlad посмотрю ознакомлюсь но мне нужна динамическая таблица которая будет подтягивать данные с бд , а таких покрайней мере бесплатных аналогов я не находил

Comment: И где об этом сказано в вопросе? Тогда надо пользоваться произвольными полями и, возможно, кастомными типами. *Судя по твоим вопросам тебе лучше делегировать задачу специалистам.*